# When my program reads CTRL-D from standard input on Linux, why does it not convert to EOF?

Tags: c, linux, eof

Below is the program that I wrote.

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * This program reads EOF from standard input stream to store in an integer 
 * variable and in a character variable. Both values are then output to see the
 * stored value as integer.
*******************************************************************************/
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    /* Local Declarations */
    int        num;
    char       ch;

    /* Read EOF as character & integer and display values stored */
    printf("\nPlease only input EOF for all input prompts below");
    printf("\nNumber? ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("\nThat integer input converts to %d", num);
    printf("\nCharacter? ");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);
    printf("\nThat character input converts to %d", ch);

    /* Check if any of the stored values are recognized as EOF */
    if(num == EOF)
        printf("\nNumber is an EOF");
    if(ch == EOF)
        printf("\nCharacter is an EOF");

    /* Exit Program */
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}// main()
```

I compiled using gcc on Ubuntu 11.10. It does not recognize <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> for EOF in the program and outputs 0 when trying to print its value. The output for the above program on my terminal is below.

```
Please only input EOF for all input prompts below
Number? 
That integer input converts to 0
Character? 
That character input converts to 0
```

NOTE: CTRL-D is not echoed by the terminal when I press it for the two inputs, hence not visible in the above program execution.

I have read that EOF is defined as an integer in stdio.h and stdlib.h and is traditionally defined as -1. Also, I understand that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> simulates EOF for standard input. Then why does it not translate to -1 when storing it to an integer variable?

Comment: Your program should call `fflush` and have the `\n` at the *end* of `printf` format strings!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank you for pointing that out. I must flush the stream for reading an int value before starting to read a character value. But why do you suggest putting `\n` at the end of `printf` format strings rather than beginning? I have seen this convention in the [book](http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Science-Structured-Programming-Approach/dp/0534491324/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1333444401&sr=8-3) I am using to learn C and found it a bit odd.

Comment: Because many implementations of `printf` are flushing the output buffer on `\n` newline characters. So your book is wrong in that aspect, you really should take the habit of putting it at the end of your format strings. And this is what most Linux utilities (e.g. shells, `make`, or `gcc` itself) are doing.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Flushing the output buffer on EOL? I thought the output stream is flushed when the file marker is placed on EOF. Please tell us more (I see you are a GCC developer:-).

Comment: Learn more about the `setlinebuf` function. On Linux (and probably on Posix systems), when *stdout* is a terminal, it usually is line buffered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `scanf("%d")` will attempt to read characters representing a number and then store that into the given variable.

It does *not* store `EOF` into the number if you close the stream. Otherwise how would you tell the difference between end of file and entering the numeric value of `EOF` (-1).

The `scanf` will return the number of items scanned (which will be zero if format was wrong, or EOF if the stream closed or certain errors occurred). It returns this as the return code from the `scanf` function, *not* via the pointer variable you passed to it.

You should only assume the variables (that you pass in the addresses for) are populated if the return value from `scanf` tells you so.

In other words, you're looking for something like:

```
int rc = scanf ("%d", &num);
switch (rc) {
    case EOF: {
        printf ("EOF returned\n");
        break;
    }
    case 0: {
        printf ("No items scanned\n");
        break;
    }
    default: {
        printf ("Scanned %d\n", num);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: So this means that when EOF is found in a stream, it is closed and not passed to the corresponding stream pointer (or variable)? And that there is no way we can read EOF from a stream into a variable?

Comment: Yes, you can read it into a variable just fine - see my code that puts it into `rc`. What you can't do is have it magically appear into `num` - that's only populated if there's a number made available on the input stream. There are two (or more) pieces of information coming back from `scanf` - the return code gives you an error indication or number of items scanned, the variable pointers you passed in give you the actual values scanned (if any).

Comment: I found a new problem based on our discussion here. I have to write a function that returns only positive integers. If the user enters otherwise, it is discarded and prompts user to input again. I implemented the function with this piece of code `do{ scanf("%d", &num) } while(num < 0);`. However, the question also specifies that if the user were to enter EOF, the function should return it as well. This is where I hit a wall, because no matter what I try I cannot take the EOF from the input stream and store it in the variable pointer passed, just as you advised. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html):

"If the input ends before the first matching failure or conversion, EOF shall be returned. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set, EOF shall be returned"

Note that it is returned, rather than being read into the pointer you pass.

To distinguish between an error and EOF you can use [`feof`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/feof.html).